# Python IRC Client

Tags: python

When I run the script:

```
import socket
from time import strftime

time = strftime("%H:%M:%S")

irc = 'irc.tormented-box.net'
port = 6667
channel = '#tormented'
sck = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sck.connect((irc, port))
print sck.recv(4096)
sck.send('NICK supaBOT\r\n')
sck.send('USER supaBOT supaBOT supaBOT :supaBOT Script\r\n')
sck.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n')
sck.send('PRIVMSG #tormented :supaBOT\r\n')
while True:
     data = sck.recv(4096)
     if data.find('PING') != -1:
        sck.send('PONG ' + data.split() [1] + '\r\n')
     elif data.find ( 'PRIVMSG' ) != -1:
        nick = data.split ( '!' ) [ 0 ].replace ( ':', '' )
        message = ':'.join ( data.split ( ':' ) [ 2: ] )
        destination = ''.join ( data.split ( ':' ) [ :2 ] ).split ( ' ' ) [ -2 ]
        if destination == 'supaBOT':
          destination = 'PRIVATE'
        print '(', destination, ')', nick + ':', message
        get = message.split(' ') [1]
        if get == 'hi':
           try:
               args = message.split(' ') [2:]
               sck.send('PRIVMSG ' + destination + ' :' + nick + ': ' + 'hello' + '\r\n')
           except:
               pass
```

I get this is the error:

```
get = message.split(' ')[1]

IndexError: list index out of range
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Aargh that typo reminds me of: http://pythong.org/ (warning: you can't unsee this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This means that `message` has no spaces in it, so when it's split by a space, you get a list containing a single element - you are trying to access the second element of this list. You should insert a check for this case.

**EDIT:** In reply to your comment: how you add the check depends on the logic of your program. The simplest solution would be something like:

```
if ' ' in msg:
    get = message.split(' ')[1]
else:
    get = message
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
get = message.split(" ",1)[-1]
```

Example

```
>>> "abcd".split(" ",1)[-1]
'abcd'
>>> "abcd efgh".split(" ",1)[-1]
'efgh'
```